# about building a small docker image from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, package, yocto

All,
   I am trying to build a Docker image to run my python 2 App within an embedded system which has OS yocto. Since the embedded system has limited flash, I want to have a small Docker image. However, after I install all the python and other packages, I get an image with 730M, which is too big for me. I don't know how to compress the image. Please share your wisdom.

Thanks!!

My Dcokerfile is like below:

```
FROM *****/base-rootfs:yocto-2.1.1
RUN opkg update
RUN opkg install *****toolchain
RUN opkg install python-pip
RUN opkg install python-dev
RUN opkg install python
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install scipy
RUN pip install sklearn
COPY appa /opt/app/
RUN chmod 777 /opt/app/main.py
CMD ["python", "./opt/app/main.py"]
```

Comment: just so I understand it right; you have a base image created through a "yocto" (e.g. the OpenEmbedded based poky distribution) build, and the corresponding package repositories, and based an *THAT* you want to create a docker image?

Comment: Yes, I try to build (add python and corresponding packages) new image based on the "yocto".

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** How to reduce the size of my docker image?

**A:** There are a few ways you can do this. The most prominent thing I can immediately spot from your Dockerfile is that you are installing packages using individual `RUN` command.

While this can make your code look a bit cleaner but each `RUN` statement is an overhead in size because docker images are build from `layers`.

To docker, each `RUN` statement is like building a new `layer` from the previous one and wrapping it around the previous one.

I think you should see a drop in size if you reduce the amount of `layers` by bundling the packages into single installation command. Maybe try grouping the `pip` ones together and `opkg` into another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I combine the RUN together, like below:
    RUN opkg install *****toolchain python python-dev python-pip
    RUN pip install numpy pandas scipy sklearn

The image size is still 730M. I wonder may be the packages need to take such big space?

Comment: I am not familiar with `opkg` package manager and the `OS` you are using. Another thing you can try is spin up the `image` as a container then `docker exec [CONTAINER_NAME] bash` to get inside the container. Browse around the container and take note of files that can be potentially be removed. Consolidate these removable files into a "cleanup" shell script and add a line in your `Dockerfile` to run that clean up script to free up size. Let me know if this helps

Comment: In `apt` package manager we can do `apt-get clean` to free up spaces as much as 100mb. Just wondering do `opkg` has something similar. I checked its documentation a bit but can't seem to find any. You're more familiar with it, maybe you can try investigate that area a bit.

Comment: Thanks, Samuel! Let me try your suggestions. Today, I use the " docker-slim " to compress the image. It compresses to 272MB. However, when I "docker exec -it conainter_ID bash", I can't use opkg to install packages and I don't know why. I can use this way to install the package in the uncompressed version though

Comment: No worries. That solution I got there didn't really help you. Anyway glad to know about `docker-slim` that is something new to me. I'll have a look at it. 730 -> 272 is really a huge gain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker history command to see which layer is causing more disk space addition.

```
docker@default:~Example>> docker history {image-name}:{image-tag}
docker@default:~$ docker history mysql
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
5195076672a7        5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["mysqld"]               0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 3306/tcp              0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entryâ¦   0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entrypâ¦   34B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:05922d368ede3042â¦   5.92kB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/var/lib/mysql]      0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c {   echo mysql-community-server mâ¦   256MB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/aâ¦   56B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.21-â¦   0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7          0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -ex;  key='A4A9406876FCBD3C45â¦   23kB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get installâ¦   44.7MB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d    0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c set -x  && apt-get update && apt-â¦   4.44MB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.7         0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get installâ¦   10.2MB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -â¦   329kB
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>           5 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:e3250bb9848f956bdâ¦   55.3MB
docker@default:~$
```

Based on output you can see and compare results with the real size of those packages and eventually drill down to what causing such a huge docker image ?